# org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception

Tags: apache-kafka

i'm getting this exception while consuming small batches from kafka and using commitAsync

```
couldn't ack 17 messages
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
```

It's look like the __consumer_offset topic wasn't able to replicate within 5 seconds (default of offsets.commit.timeout.ms).

In other consumers of the same application where I commiting larger batches to kafka I can't see this error

```
config.put("client.id", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + "_" + clientId + "_" + Thread.currentThread());
        config.put("group.id", "some-id");
        config.put("bootstrap.servers", clusterUrl);
        config.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        config.put("heartbeat.interval.ms", 3000);
        config.put("session.timeout.ms", 60000);
        config.put("request.timeout.ms", 60000 + 5000);
        config.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        config.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        config.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        config.put("fetch.min.bytes", 1000000);
        config.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", 1000000);
        config.put("fetch.max.wait.ms", 50);
```

What can cause this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the concept of kafka connect.
When we get retriable exception , consumer commit will not happen and same batch will be retried again.

It will be retried 10 times by deffault with a try interval of 3 seconds.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#retries

Comment: We are not using kafka connect, we use it with java - why those retriable commits happens with small batches ?

Comment: We are also running into the same issue and we also dont use kafka-connect